# How to protect access to this endpoint from a single Windows machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, endpoint

How to protect access to this endpoint from a single Windows machine.

**URL:** https://test.rev.com:443/press/api/v1/receiver

Need to avoid POST access from any other machine in AWS

Comment: Is that a custom built API endpoint running on a computer instance within AWS or it's an AwS service like API Gateway?

Comment: @Nick The endpoint is pointing to an ALB

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response that the endpoint in question is an ALB what you can do is to update the  [security group associated with that application load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html)

In the inbound rules add the following:

- Security group ID of the SG attached to the windows machine --> 443 (if you don't want to be that strict you can allow all traffic from that instance and leave the port to any).

In the outbound rules add the ones mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html)

- Security group ID of the target instance --> target instance listener port
- Security group ID of the target instance --> target instance health check port